# Как в картах react-native-yamap и настроить поиск по гео?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, react-native, map

Начал строить приложение на RN и появилась необходимость в поиске адреса по гео. Подключил карты https://github.com/volga-volga/react-native-yamap, но совершенно не понятно как применить модуль по гео

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предполагаю, что данный метод связывается с маркером, реализовать его на своём примере мне не получилось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В самом репозитории react-native-yamap ведь есть примеры. Посмотрите по [поиску](https://github.com/volga-volga/react-native-yamap/search?q=suggest)

Comment: Спасибо, лучшие практики всегда спасают)